# Etymology of the word "isotropic"

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, quadratic-forms

Given a quadratic form $q : V \rightarrow k$, a nonzero vector $v \in V$ is said to be *isotropic* if $q(v) = 0$.  Any subspace of $V$ containing such a vector is also said to be isotropic, and the quadratic form itself is *also* said to be isotropic.  The word "isotropic" is Greek for "the same in every direction."  What does this have to do with being a zero of a quadratic form?

Comment: Still working, meanwhile Google turned up this wonderful pdf http://isotropic.org/papers/chicken.pdf

Comment: Alright, I think there is some reason to blame Ernst Witt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Witt but should point out that solving $a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2$ goes back to Legendre, while the relation to the $p$-adic fields is typically called Hasse-Minkowski.

Comment: @Will: This is even more off-topic, but I just have to share: https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=1388783232809

Comment: @Zev, this is the second time recently that the computer told me I needed Adobe Flash, which I could have sworn I had. A frind tells me I need a new modem. I will see your video before too long.

Comment: Zev, thank you so much for sharing that.

Comment: $5 to the first person to publish a paper citing chicken.pdf in a peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: From Mariano, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL_-1d9OSdk

Comment: @Will: carrying a gag too far, but [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RDQvl.gif) is what prompted that paper and presentation.

Comment: @J.M. I don't see that Zongker gives proper attribution to McLaren and Spacek. He does cite Chicken and Chicken.

Comment: @Will: Well, I'm told that's what their names translate to in the newly proposed language... :D

Comment: Hello, I'm Greek and the exact etymology of the word "isotropic" is this: "iso" means 'equal' just as "isometry,isomorphism,isosceles triangle" etc. "Tropos" means the way you do something, I guess that A and B could be called isotropic because something in A and B is being done with the exact way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Mariano found this [LECTURE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL_-1d9OSdk)

I have borrowed *Quadratische Formen und Orthogonale Gruppen* by Martin Eichler, Springer-Verlag 1952.

On page 3

> Ist $\xi$ zu sich selber senkrecht und $\xi \neq 0,$ so nennt man
>   $\xi$ einen *isotropen Vektor*. Enthält $R$ keinen isotropen
>   Vektor, so soll $R$ *anisotrop* heißen, im anderen Fall *isotrop*.

Then section 3 of chapter one begins on page 12, with the title

> Die Automorphismengruppe eines isotropen Raumes

Varied other German endings occur throughout; the index says pages 3, 12ff, 57ff, 99ff.

It is difficult to say whether Eichler feels he is introducing new terminology. The word isotropic comes from physics, materials science, biology and other places in mathematics as well. If this is important, the thing to do is get on MathSciNet and look up occurrences of the word isotropic in reviews under subject headings related to quadratic forms, integral lattices, and so on. That takes you back to slightly before 1940. Do the same with Zentralblatt. Also look up the collected works of Hasse, then of Minkowski.

In the Vorwort, he does seem to be acknowledging a debt to the book(s) of P. Bachmann, *Arithmetik der quadratischen Formen*, part I 1898,  part II 1923.

Comment: \ss and \"a respectively.

The other uses of "isotropic" in other areas mathematics seem to make sense, in that there's some sense of something being the same in all directions.  What I can't see is how you get from there to here.  Perhaps I should have asked for a motivation rather than an etymology.

Comment: All right, this question seems to be more about chickens than isotropic forms now, so I guess I'll go ahead and accept this answer and resign.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury , on the plus side, I was just walking around the nearby pond, and saw about a dozen egrets in the same tree, also a black crowned night heron. $$ $$ The point about isotropy is not about a single field, it is about combining information from all the $p$-adic fields. It is a matter of low dimension. In five or more variables, all integral forms are isotropic in every $p$-adic field, even when there are still restrictions, as for, say, $$ v^2 + 3 w^2 + 3 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 3 z^2 $$ which is never $2 \pmod 3.$

Comment: @DanielMcLaury take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/isotropy-over-p-adic-numbers/ and email me if you are still unhappy. I cannot tell what you want.

Comment: If you need to type non-math special characters that aren't on your keyboard, the easy way is to copy-and-paste them from the Wikipedia articles (e.g. [umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29) and [eszett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eszett)).

Comment: @RahulNarain, thanks.

Comment: I still can't make sense of this word. @WillJagy, were you saying that an isotropic quadratic form is "the same in all directions" where a "direction" is a $p$-adic field? Could you add something about that to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am becoming pretty confident that this goes back to Ernst Witt. German forms of the word include "isotrop," "isotrope," and "isotropen." You can download a 1970  article using these by Winfried Scharlau for free at

[Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01433278)

Pretty much everyone refers to an article in Crelle's journal, which is now
Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, by Ernst Witt, *Theorie der quadratischen Formen in beliebigen K$\ddot{o}$rpern,* volume **176** pages 31-44,   (1937).

Alright, I was able to read the Witt article on the Goettingen archives of the journal. Every place the concept came up, Witt uses the word Null as a noun.

Note that Leonard Eugene Dickson always referred to zero forms. Most of the terminology in English was standardized by 1963, in *Introduction to Quadratic Forms* by O. Timothy O'Meara.  So perhaps it moved from English back to German.

Another really groundbreaking book was Martin Eichler in 1952, *Quadratische Formen und orthogonale Gruppen*. Eichler introduced the spinor genus, which codifies behavior of psitive ternary forms found by Jones and Pall in 1939.

I tried. I really did.

Comment: The paper doesn't include the word "isotropy" or any recognizable form of it.  I'm reading it right now to see if the concept is mentioned and named.

Comment: You're correct. I'm just seeing the word Null.

Comment: The earliest document I have that definitely uses the word is the O'Meara book. He gives a ton of credit to the Eichler book, so it may be worth borrowing that. Sorry about Witt, it really seemed promising.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard an answer that is pure motivation and contains no historical work--but maybe it's not too hair-brained.  A physicist probably was implicitly thinking of the quadratic form as the second fundamental form associated to a parametrized surface $z=f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Roughly speaking, this quadratic form defines the curvature at a given point.  In this sense, if the quadratic form vanishes, then the curvature is zero, and indeed things look the same in all directions!

As far as post hoc rationalizations go, how bad could this be?

Comment: $z=x^2-y^2$ is isotropic as a quadratic form, but not isotropic as a curved surface.