# Isotropic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Etymology of the word “isotropic”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90674/etymology-of-the-word-isotropic)

Let $V$ be a vector space and we have a symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear form with signature $(n,n)$ on it. A subspace $L$ is said to be Isotropic if $(x,y)=0$ for all $x$, $y\in L$.

My question is about the name "Isotropic". As I know, isotrophy means "there is no specific direction". I mean, it has a geometric meaning. In this context I cannot see why we say that $L$ is isotropic if it satisfies such a condition.