# Is there a name for "positive-semidefinite" quadratic forms when the base field is not $\mathbb R$?

Tags: terminology, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form, positive-semidefinite

Consider a vector space $V$, with a symmetric bilinear form $\cdot$ , over a field $\mathbb F$ with characteristic not $2$.

Suppose, for any $x\in V$, if $x\cdot x=0$, then $x=0$. What is this property called? I might say that the form is *definite*, or perhaps *formally positive-definite* in analogy with formally real fields (where any sum of nonzero squares is nonzero). Indeed if $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ then this is equivalent to the usual meaning of definiteness.

But it's not equivalent for other ordered fields. For  example, the rational form $\mathbb Q^2\ni(x_1,x_2)\mapsto(x_1,x_2)^2=x_1^2-2x_2^2$ has this property since $\sqrt2$ is irrational, even though the form is indefinite according to the order on $\mathbb Q$. And in general $\mathbb F$ needn't be ordered, so "positive-definite" is meaningless, though the above property is still meaningful.

Similarly, I might say that the form is *semidefinite*, or *formally positive-semidefinite*, if this condition holds: For any $x\in V$, if $x\cdot x=0$, then $x$ is in the degenerate subspace $V^\perp\subseteq V$ (also called the "radical" of $V$), meaning $x\cdot y=0$ for all $y\in V$. Another characterization of this is that $V$ contains no "hyperbolic planes": 2D subspaces where the quadratic form is like $(x_1,x_2)^2=2x_1x_2$ or $x_1^2-x_2^2$. This is equivalent to the usual meaning of semidefiniteness when $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$.

Are there standard terms for these properties? If not, what do you suggest?

---

Commenters have reminded me of "anisotropic" for the first property (though the term doesn't make sense to me; see [Etymology of the word "isotropic"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/90674/472818)). The second property remains.

---

Here's another description of those properties, in terms of the origin $O=\{0\in V\}$, the radical $R=V^\perp=\{x\in V\mid\forall y\in V, x\cdot y=0\}$, and the null cone $C=\{x\in V\mid x\cdot x=0\}$. It's clear that $O\subseteq R\subseteq C\subseteq V$. The form is *nondegenerate* when $O=R$. The form is *anisotropic* when $O=C$. What is the form when $R=C$?

Comment: This is not positive definite. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form

Comment: "anisotropic" is therefore the word you're looking for