# Is there a first-order logical description of a quadratic form being hyperbolic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Here we consider finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ with quadratic forms over a field $\mathbb F$ where $2\neq0$. A *hyperbolic plane* is any space isomorphic to $\mathbb F^2$ with the quadratic form $x\mapsto x_1^2-x_2^2$, or equivalently $x\mapsto x_1x_2$. A *hyperbolic space* is a direct sum of hyperbolic planes. A *null vector* is an element $x\in V$ mapped to $0\in\mathbb F$ by the quadratic form; we write this as $x\cdot x=0$, using a dot for the bilinear form. The *trivial subspace* is $O=\{0\}\subseteq V$.

According to Witt's Decomposition Theorem (7.6 in [Pete Clark's notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/quadraticforms.pdf)), any space can be expressed as a direct sum

$$V=K\oplus H\oplus N$$

where $K\setminus O$ has no null vectors, $H$ is hyperbolic, and $N$ has only null vectors. ($K$ is the "anisotropic kernel" of $V$, and $N$ is the "radical" of $V$.) Furthermore, this decomposition is essentially unique; if $V=K\oplus H\oplus N=K'\oplus H'\oplus N'$, then $K\cong K'$ and $H\cong H'$ and $N=N'$.

$V$ is *non-degenerate* when $N=O$, or equivalently

$$\forall x\in V,\;(\forall y\in V,\;x\cdot y=0)\implies x=0.$$

$V$ is *anisotropic* when $H=N=O$, or equivalently

$$\forall x\in V,\;x\cdot x=0\implies x=0.$$

The property [without a name](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3951430/472818), $H=O$, is equivalent to

$$\forall x\in V,\;x\cdot x=0\implies(\forall y\in V,\;x\cdot y=0).$$

$V$ is *totally isotropic* when $K=H=O$, or equivalently

$$\forall x\in V,\;x\cdot x=0.$$

$V$ is *hyperbolic* when $K=N=O$. Is there any such equivalent description of this?

If the dimension of $V$ is fixed, for example $4$, then of course we can just say there exists a basis with specified dot products:

$$\exists w\in V,\;\exists x\in V,\;\exists y\in V,\;\exists z\in V,\;(w\cdot w=x\cdot x=y\cdot y=z\cdot z \\ =w\cdot y=w\cdot z=x\cdot y=x\cdot z=0\neq w\cdot x=y\cdot z).$$

Comment: The issue I am running into is the the decomposition of $V$ is really highly non-unique. Consider just the case $V = \mathbb Fv\oplus H$ for some non-null $v \in V$ orthogonal to $H$. We can then say $V = \mathbb Fv'\oplus H'$ where $v'$ is **any vector in $H$** with $v'\cdot v'$ in the same square class as $v\cdot v$, and $H' = (\mathbb Fv')^\perp$ is also hyperbolic.

Comment: I think that $V$ is hyperbolic iff $V$ is non-degenerate and $\exists W\leq V.\:W^\perp = W$ where $\leq$ means "is a subspace of". This makes it feel inherently second-order to me.

Comment: Well, it's unique up to isomorphism. -- I'm also getting the feeling that it's second-order.