# Square classes of $\mathbb{Q}_2^\times$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Does anyone know how to easily compute them? We know that a number is a square modulo $2^k$ if and only if it's a square modulo $8$. This gives a bunch of integers that represent square classes. I also know that

$$\mathbb{Q}_2^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}\times (1+2\mathbb{Z}_2),$$

but I can't figure out how to find the square classes in $1+2\mathbb{Z}_2$. Is there some really simple solution for this? I can't seem to figure out how to apply Hensel's lemma here.

Comment: Maybe my little knowledge is a dangerous thing, but why isn't the answer simply everything of the form $2^k (1 + 8z)$, where $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $z \in {\mathbb Z}_2$?

Comment: @GregMartin:  $k$ has to be even.

Comment: @CamMcLeman: sorry yes of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your observations, a square element of $1+2\mathbb{Z}_2$ must actually live in $1+8\mathbb{Z}_2$.  So 
$$
\mathbb{Q}_2^\times/\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times 2}\approx \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \frac{1+2\mathbb{Z}_2}{1+8\mathbb{Z}_2}\approx \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.
$$
The first factor of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to choosing even/odd-ness of the power of 2 dividing the element of $\mathbb{Q}_2^\times$, the latter two any choice of coset represenatives for odd squares mod 8.  So one possible enumeration of representatives for these 8 classes are the classes of
$$
\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 5,\pm 10\}.
$$

Comment: Cam, that is the choice on page 43 of Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. There was some poor slob a few months ago here on MSE who wanted to know the primes for which some indefinite ternary, diagonal such as $3 x^2 + 7 y^2 - 15 z^2,$ was isotropic. I typed it all in but I do not believe it took. Oh, also he wouldn't buy Cassels, he "had no access" to it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/isotropy-over-p-adic-numbers

Comment: @WillJagy:  Indeed, I'm at the moment the unique upvote on that answer.  :)

And it appears that this particular class of representatives is a heavy favorite -- I quickly checked, and both Gouvea and Serre use it as well!

Comment: Thanks, Cam, I do like to  educate the OP, but that takes time, and often  they want just enough to do the homework, but quickly. I see, both answers there were mine, after the OP said the first answer wasn't good enough. Sigh.