How to explicitly find representatives of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times})^2$?
How to explicitly find representatives of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times})^2$? I for example know that $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times})^2 \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$ if $p \ne 2$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ if $p=2$.
I ask this in the context of elliptic curves. We have, for example, $$E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{cts}(\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{K}/K),E(\mathbb{Q}[2])$$ that maps $P \mapsto \phi_P$ where $\phi_P(g)=g\left(\frac{1}{2}P\right)\ominus \frac{1}{2}P$ and is an injective homomorphism. So, the curve $E:y^2=x(x-5)(x+5)$ has a map
$$E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Q}^\times/(\mathbb{Q}^{\times})^2)^3$$
$$P=(x_0,y_0) \rightarrow (x_0, x_0-5,x_0+5),$$
and so then possible triples $(a,b,c)$ lie in the image $a,b,c \in \pm \{\pm1,\pm2,\pm5,\pm10\}$. How do we know that $a,b,c$ lie in $\pm \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5, \pm 10\}$? How do we get these numbers? Another example is $y^2=x(x-3)(x+6)$, then $a,b,c \in \pm \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 6\}$. I presume this has something to do with units and non-units in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, but I am not sure.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98251/square-classes-of-mathbbq-2-times. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

see Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. On pages 42 and 43 he lists the squareclasses. For detail he refers to Cassels and Frohlich (1967)  or Serre, Local Fields, https://archive.org/details/localfields0000serr/page/n5/mode/2up where you can register  and "borrow" the book online. For an odd prime $p$ the squareclasses, using $n$  as a quadratic nonresidue, are $1, n, p, np.$  For the prime $\infty$  the squareclasses are $1,-1$

@Tri Thank you so much, that is indeed helpful!

@WillJagy Thank you, that does solve my query, have a good day!
