# Quadratic forms over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

*How to solve a problem like this:*

Find out which elements $N \in \mathbb N$ are represented by the quadratic form $\left \langle 2,3,2 \right \rangle$ in $\mathbb Q$.

The form is $$  f(x,y,z) = 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 z^2.  $$

Do I have to reduce it modulo all primes $p \in \mathbb P\cup \left \{ \infty \right \}$ and use a local-global principle?

Comment: Is this the binary form $2 x^2 + 3 x y + 2 y^2$ or the diagonal ternary form $2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 z^2?   $

Comment: It is the diagonal ternary form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDDDITTTT: I notice you also asked about the Hilbert norm residue symbol. So the best thing you can do is get [CASSELS](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html) and look through the first 60 pages. What you do is begin with
$$  2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 z^2 = n  $$ and switch to
$$  2 x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 z^2 - n t^2 = 0.  $$ You especially want the table of the symbol on page 43 and the conditions for isotropy on pages 58-59. I have gone through the whole song and dance for an answer here on MSE, I think it was an indefinite form. If I find it I will put in a link. [Isotropy over $p$-adic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/isotropy-over-p-adic-numbers)

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Anything needed is at [TERNARY](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html)

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** This answer (wrongly) assumed that the question was about binary quadratic forms.

You should read the first few chapters of the book by Cox, "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$", or the chapter on quadratic forms in Davenport's "Higher Arithmetic". The basic steps are these:

- First, I will talk about representation in $\mathbb{Z}$, since you can always multiply through by denominators. The general answer differs from this one by squares.
- The discriminant of the form is -7. General theory shows that a number $N$ is properly represented by *some* form of discriminant $d$ if and only if $d$ is a square modulo $4|N|$. Properly represented means represented by coprime $x,y$. The numbers that are represented in *some* way, properly or not, are multiples of the properly represented ones by squares (see first point). So the two problems of representation and proper representation are easily translatable into each other.
- Use quadratic reciprocity to explicate the above condition in the case $d=-7$.
- Reduction theory shows that every form of discriminant $d<0$ is equivalent by a linear change of variables with determinant 1 to a so-called reduced form. Forms that are equivalent to each other represent the same set of integers. Reduced forms have nice and easy coefficients, among other things they satisfy $0<a\leq \sqrt{|d|/3}$ and $|b|\leq a$. Moreover, $d$ is odd if and only if $b$ is, since $d=b^2-4ac$.
- Deduce from the reduction theory that there is actually only one reduced form of discriminant -7 (the inequalities imply that $a=1$, $b=\pm 1$, but the $b=-1$ case is equivalent to the $b=1$ case). Thus, the congruence conditions that you got in the third bullet point are actually the necessary and sufficient conditions for a number to be properly representable by the unique equivalence class of forms of discriminant -7.

The theory becomes much more difficult (and interesting) if there are several equivalence classes of the given discriminant. Also, positive discriminant is harder, because reduction theory is harder.

Comment: It's a shame the question was ambiguous and not clarified until after this answer was posted.

Comment: I also thought it was probably the binary form, otherwise why write it that way out of order.

Comment: I'm sorry about confusion. I thought that $\left \langle a_1,a_2,...,a_n \right \rangle$ is the general notation for the quadratic form $a_1 x_1^2+ a_2 x_2^2 + ... + a_n x_n^2$.