# Why do we conclude that $(a,b)=1$, having found that $(a',b'=1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose that we have the equation $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0, a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Without loss of generality, we suppose that $gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

Also, we can consider that $a,b,c$ are square-free.

We can suppose that $(a,b)=(b,c)=(a,c)=1$.

***Proof of the last sentence***:

Let $d=(a,b)>1$

Since $a,b$ are square-free $\Rightarrow d$ is also square-free.
$$a=da' \\ b=db'$$
$$\Rightarrow (a',b')=1$$

It stands that $(d,c)=1$.

Proof:

Let $d'=(d,c)>1$

[image]

So, when $(x,y,z)$ an integer solution of $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0 \\ \Rightarrow d(a'x^2+b'y^2)+cz^2=0 \\ \Rightarrow d \mid cz^2, (d,c)=1 \Rightarrow d \mid z^2$

Since $d$ is square-free, $d \mid z^2 \Rightarrow d \mid z \Rightarrow z=dz'$

The initial equation:
 $$a'x^2+b'y^2+(cd)z^2=0$$

We concluded to an equivalent equation, where $(a',b')=1$

With the same procedure,  we prove that $(a,b)=(b,c)=(c,d)=1$

Could you explain me why, having the equivalent equation, we conclude that $(a,b)=1$ ?

Comment: I really think you ought to look at this answer first. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001787/does-the-equation-has-a-non-trivial-solution/1001989#1001989

Comment: Ok, I will :-) :-)