# Why are quadratic forms that satisfy these conditions isotropic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

I'd like to know why all quadratic forms satisfy the following:

> 1) If $F$ is an algebraically closed field, for example, the field of complex numbers, and $(V, q)$ is a quadratic space of dimension at least two, then it is isotropic.

And:

> 2) If $F$ is the field $Q_p$ of p-adic numbers and $(V, q)$ is a quadratic space of dimension at least five, then it is isotropic.

Any insight on these two is greatly appreciated.

Comment: recommend Cassels, inexpensive http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html

Comment: You need to state clearly what is $(V,q)$ and what means isotropic. Possibly it reduces to *every positive definite matrix is diagonalizable over the algebraic closure*.

Comment: Isotropic means nontrivial kernel and $(V, q)$ is simply the quadratic form $q:V \rightarrow F$

Answer (score 0):

On the first one, from Cassels. He  has characteristic not two. He does not say that all forms can be diagonalised over a field, he says that there is a normal basis. We use the polarization identity to get an inner product $\phi,$ a normal basis has $\phi(u_i, u_j) = 0$ when $i \neq j.$  Therefore the form applied to a vector becomes $\sum a_i x_i^2.$ Over an algebraically closed field, we can take all but the first two $x_i$ zero, then take $x_2 = 1,$ and solve for $x_1$ in $a_1 x_1^2 + a_2 = 0.$

The dimension 5 bit is a longer story. I recommend Cassels because he is focused on the rational numbers and the rational integers, he does isotropy for the $p$-adics in great and understandable detail. This includes tables for the Hilbert norm residue symbol, pages  43 and 44, with which the isotropy results are proved, pages 58-60 primarily. Your question is Lemma 2.7, page 60. The proof is pigeonhole on the $p$-adic squareclasses

Comment: @reuns yes, my $x_i = \langle x,u_i\rangle.$ Cassels does use the word diagonal later in the book.

Comment: So $\sum_i a_i \langle x,u_i\rangle^2$ the diagonalized form. And what is special over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ (and $\dim(V) \ge 5$) ?

Comment: @reuns, he shows that any ternary represents all but one p-adic squareclass. The remaining binary part (out of dimension 5), rather $-1$ times the binary section, represents half the squareclasses. Thus there is a nonzero element represented by both pieces. Hmmm, then he says he has already proved it for prime $p \neq 2$ in Lemma 1.7, Corollary, of Chapter 3, page 41. Good to know.

Comment: Tks, your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/isotropy-over-p-adic-numbers) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem) gives some clues